# Form POST in html email doesn't see variable in PHP

Tags: php, html

i send an HTML email with a form and a button like this:

```
<form action="http://myurl/index.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="testing" value="123456">
<button  class="btn" type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

then in my index.php page i read the `testing` variable, in this way:

```
echo $_POST['testing'];
```

but i can't read the variable and give me this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: testing
```

there is a way to send a variabile from an html mail to a php page?

Comment: this button of yours should be: `<button  class="btn" type="submit" value="SEND">`

Comment: This form is on the same page `index.php` or another one?

Comment: the form is on a html email...i wrote it in the first line of the question...

Comment: @JorgeCampos The value inside the submit button is only useful if he'd actually check if SEND is present in `$_POST`.

TO add here: in HTML 5 the button is fine, in HTML 4 or XHTML it should actually be `<input class="btn" type="submit" value="SEND">` - button has no value attribute.

Comment: Try putting in the start of your `index.php` the line: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @JohannesH. thanks didn't know about this sintax on html 5

Comment: @Piero Most likely you're reading `$_POST` even if there was no data submitted. If the script that has the php code inside is the same as the one with the html form, you only get the data when sending the form, not on the initial request. Therefore you have to check first if there was data submitted: `<?php  
if (isset($_POST['testing'])) {  
  echo $_POST['testing'];  
}`

Comment: Another thing to check is test your form outside the email. Some email clients prevent post data for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. Got that Email Part now.

Most Mail-Programs won't do POST requests, for security/privacy reasons. Use GET here:

in HTML:
`<a href="http://myurl/index.php?testing=123456">SEND</a>`
and in PHP:
`echo $_GET['testing']`

Of course the data is visible in that case - but that's the entire point.

Comment: I went back and re-read it as well. I thought you meant you were posting to a script from another script already on the website, not from an e-mail that posts to a script. In that case this answer is your best bet but I do recommend using at least urlencode() to send your data and urldecode() when you pull it from the URL. If the contents of the data are sensitive you're going to need to re-think this approach all together.

Comment: @rsmith84: I agree, sensitive data should not be sent that way. Best don't send any sensitive data by email at all. At least not unencrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Emails don't play well with a lot of fairly standard html.  In this case, I'd use something like this:

```
<a href="http://myurl/index.php?testing=123456">Submit</a>
```

And then style your anchor to look like a button.  Then on your php side, use this to make sure the variable gets there:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you replace:

```
<button  class="btn" type="submit">SEND</button>
```

With

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

I realize you are probably styling it given that you have a class statement but you can still style an input type="submit" easily enough. I ran into issues posting variables using the  object.

Also, FWIW, you don't need to specify the full URL in the action. In fact, you should probably do the following to safeguard your self against XSS attacks:

```
<form action="<? echo htmlentities('/path/to/index.php'); ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: The full url is needed in this case as the form is in an email, so it will be posting to another server.